# Retrieve CampaignResponse Details from CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have a Created a campaign in the CRM. Now users register for this Campaign and the results are stored as CampaignResponse objects.

I need to retrieve the details of a particular CampaignResponse by a given Email Id.

Can someone please tell me how can i achieve this!!
Any help would be appreciated.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Is your campaign response a response related to an email generated by a campaign activity?

If so, you just have to retrieve the campaign response with the originating activity that points to the Email Activity created by the Campaign Activity.